# how to retain the selected value of dropdown list when page is refreshed

Tags: php

Hi I am doing a shopping cart.I need to know that when the user changes the option, the new option should be set as default even after refreshing the page.How can I do it? Please help me

Comment: Cookies or session variables

Comment: Perhaps a bit devious but local storage or store the cart server side should also work.

Answer (score 2):

When the user selects the option, try to save the option in a `cookie or a session by using a ajax call`.

So, even if the page is refreshed, if the cookie or session variable is set, then you can make it as default using the `"selected"` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with javascript only. Here i am using jquery library for javascript , as most preferred.

***logic**

As user select from dropdown you can  can save the data in cokkie and on page load you can retrieve value from cokkie and set it in option back.

and by using this plugin you can eaisly do this

See the plugin:
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

     if (jQuery.cookie('choosed')) { // checking if cokkie exist
            $('<selector select>').val($.cookie("choosed")); // assiging value in select box
        }

});
```

on form submit you can remove the cookie by using

```
if (jQuery.cookie('choosed')) { // checking if cokkie exist
         $.removeCookie("test");
    }
```

And **onchange** event of select you can set that by doing this.

```
$.cookie("choosed",$('<selector select>').val();  , {
   expires : 10,           //expires in 10 days

   path    : '/',          //The value of the path attribute of the cookie 
                       //(default: path of page that created the cookie).

   domain  : 'jquery.com',  //The value of the domain attribute of the cookie
                       //(default: domain of page that created the cookie).

   secure  : true          //If set to true the secure attribute of the cookie
                       //will be set and the cookie transmission will
                       //require a secure protocol (defaults to false).
});
```

Comment: thank you.Is there some other method?? As I am not familiar with cookies

Comment: You will need a persistent storage , that will maintain your data while page refreshing. that is only done by cookie in browser. or now days, local storage in html5 can do this.or you can choose session but then you have to make a call on server side to store that value in session variable through **ajax** as user select the option. so you can dot this by anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an *Auto Save*, that will send the variables to the server at regular intervals using ajax. Donot save these on to the database, but save them on the SESSION or cookies.

Below is a way to achieve it using the session.

Example :

```
<form action="backend.php" method="post">
    Name : <input name="name" id="name_input" class="savable" value=<?php echo $_SESSION['save_name'];?>/> <br />
    Father's name : <input name="fathername" id="fathername_input" class="savable" value=<?php echo $_SESSION['save_fathername'];?>/> 
</form>
```

You may want to check if set for the variables's `value` field.

Script:

```
function autoSave(){
    $(".savable").each(function(){
        $.ajax("save.php",{id:this.id, value:this.val()});
    });
}
```

The above function should be called at regular intervals using `setInterval()`.

save.php:

```
$key = $_POST["id"];
$val = $_POST["value"];
$_SESSION["save_".$key] = $val;
```

Hope this helps.